# How to include def function in this set of code(analyse word occurrence frequency)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python so i hope you guys can help me out. I am trying to include def function to this set of code that analyse word occurrence frequency.But i kept getting error while doing so. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!!!

```
word_freq = {}
with open('partA', 'r') as f:
   word_list = f.read().split()
   for word in word_list:
      word_freq.setdefault(word, 0)
      word_freq[word] += 1

print(word_freq)
```

Below is the output:
{'hey': 1, 'there': 1, 'This': 1, 'is': 8, 'Joey': 1, 'how': 1, 'it': 13, 'going': 1}

Comment: Paste the error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

The sintax is simple `def your_function_name(parameters):` and tabulate your code properly inside. Also notice that functions can return values so your case is convenient:

```
def word_freq(file_path)
    word_freq_dict = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        word_list = f.read().split()
        for word in word_list:
            word_freq_dict.setdefault(word, 0)
            word_freq_dict[word] += 1
    return word_freq_dict

print(word_freq("partA"))
```

Check that we use a parameter `file_path` to take the non-common part of the code, and instead of printing the values, we `return` them from the function so that way we can use them outside of it too, if you want to print them, you can just print them outside.